# How to prepopulate a field from parent form to Inline Entity Form

Tags: 8, forms

I have 2 content types - Employee and Project.

Both forms have Inline Entity Forms with references to content of each other

- when user creates an Employee node, he can add projects he took part in, and also when user creates a Project node, he can add a list of employees, who worked on this project.

But I would like to prepopulate parent node title in IEF, how can I do this?

For example, when I create a Project content type node, I add some employees, when I save Project node, these employees are mentioned on this project's node, but in the employees node there's no link to this Project.

I would like to prepopulate project title field in employees IEF project when saving Project node and vice versa. 
It sounds a little bit like recursion, and  I'm not sure that my explanation is clear but I tried my best.
I'm using Drupal 8.

Comment: Is that for Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention! I'm using Drupal 8!